# Multiple CASE expressions in select, where and group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to solve one of the brilliant problems. I would like to use case in sql to optimize the SQL stored procedure.

`ProductMetrics` table as below. This table has data about sale price and quantity of products along with product Company, Region of sale, Product Name, Market division.

Table ProductMetrics contains 10000+ rows

```
ProductMetrics
| Day | CompanyId | RegionId | ProdId | DivId | Quantity | Sale
```

We have other reference tables -

```
Company(CompanyId, CompanyName), 
Region(RegionId, RegionName),
Product(ProdId, ProductName),
Division(DivId, DivisionName)
```

User can get readable statistics from this table using below query.

```
Select m.Day, c.CompanyName, r.RegionName, p.ProductName, d.DivisionName, m.Quantity, m.Sale
from ProductMetrics m
left outer join Company on c.CompanyId = m.CompanyId
left outer join Region on r.RegionId = m.RegionId
left outer join Product on p.ProdId = m.ProdId
left outer join Division on d.DivId = m.DivId
where m.Day = '12-05-2015' and
      m.CompanyId= 15 and
      m.RegionId =10
```

I wish to have stored procedure that will get above summarized stats for particular division, or product or company or for both. SP will return based on queryParameter we pass. `getProductMetrics(queryParam, Day, CompanyId, RegionId, ProdId, DivId)` QueryParameter is given in bracket in below examples. 
For example,

1. (C) Get total quantity and sale for a particular Company. i.e. group by CompanyId
2. (CR)Total quantity and sale grouped by Company and Region. Different combinations between Company and Region.
3. (P) Total quantity and sale grouped by Company
4. (D) Get total quantity and sale for a particular division.

and so on...
QueryParameter could be of value - `C, R, P, CRP, D, CR, CP, CD`. For each queryParameter, I have select statements. For example below

```
IF @queryParameter IN ('C')
  select m.Day, c.CompanyName, 'ALL' as Region, 'ALL' as ProductName, 'ALL' as DivisionName, SUM(m.Quantity), SUM(m.Sale)
    from ProductMetrics m
    left outer join Company on c.CompanyId = m.CompanyId
    where m.Day = '12-05-2015' and
        c.CompanyId =23
    group by m.Day, c.CompanyName
```

So on..
Above Stored procedure gives me total sale for a particular Product and day from all available division, region.

To stored procedure, I need to write 8 select statments with IF condition.

Question is Rather than 8 different select statement, Should I use CASE statements to have only single storedProc ?

I tried below-

```
Select m.Day as Date,
       CASE @QueryParameter
          WHEN IN (C, CRP, CP, CR, CD) THEN c.CompanyName
          ELSE 'ALL'
        END as 'CompanyName',

        CASE @QueryParameter
          WHEN IN (R, CR) THEN r.RegionName
          ELSE 'ALL'
        END as 'RegionName',

        CASE @QueryParameter
          WHEN IN (P, CRP, CP) THEN p.ProductName
          ELSE 'ALL'
        END as 'ProductName',

        CASE @QueryParameter
          WHEN IN (D, CD) THEN d.DivisionName
          ELSE 'ALL'
        END as 'DivisionName',

        SUM(Quantity), SUM(Sale)
from ProductMetrics m,
left outer join Company on c.CompanyId = m.CompanyId
left outer join Region on r.RegionId = m.RegionId
left outer join Product on p.ProdId = m.ProdId
left outer join Division on d.DivId = m.DivId

where m.Day='12-5-2015' and
      r.Region = @region and
      p.ProdId = @product
      c.CompanyId = @company and
      d.DivId = @division
group by Day, CompanyName,RegionName, ProductName, DivisionName
```

As you know, case statements should also be present for join, where and group by statements. becuase for QueryParameter 'CR', divionId and ProdId will passed as null. 
I will run storedProc(QueryParameter, CompID, RegionId, ProdId, DivId) with below exec
`EXEC getProductMetrics('CR',23, 39, '','') // CR requires only CompID and` RegionId

```
EXEC getProductMetrics('CD',23, '', '',100) // CD requires only CompID and DivId
```

and so on..
Could you assist me in getting this optimized query?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? (Make up your mind)

Comment: SQL Server ;) I would appreciate your advice

Comment: Why do you insist on having one select statement? I would use IF...ELSE to evaluate which parameters are NULL and then produce separate select statements for them. Probably the query optimizer will handle them better then and the code will be more readable.

Comment: @PawełKucharski, Looks to be a good idea :)

Comment: Those are case expressions, not case statements.

Answer (score 2):

To do this in simple and readable manner I would create some helper logic variables like *@ByCompany*, to check if we should group by company and so on. Then I would interpret input and set those variables accordingly to it, and then create one statement that use them in *SELECT*, *WHERE* and *GROUP BY* (and probably *ORDER BY* as well) sections. I do not see need for using them in *FROM* section, though.

Below some sample code - sorry for any mistakes in TransactSQL - I did not use it for a while now. ;)

```
DECLARE @ByCompany BIT = 0;
DECLARE @ByRegion BIT = 0;
[..]
IF @QueryParameter LIKE ('%C%') @ByCompany = 1
IF @QueryParameter LIKE ('%R%') @ByRegion = 1
[..]
Select 
    m.Day as Date,
    CASE @ByCompany WHEN 1 THEN c.CompanyName ELSE 'ALL' END as 'CompanyName',
    CASE @ByRegion  WHEN 1 THEN r.RegionName  ELSE 'ALL' END as 'RegionName',
    [..]
    SUM(Quantity), 
    SUM(Sale)
from 
    ProductMetrics m,
left outer join Company on c.CompanyId = m.CompanyId
left outer join Region on r.RegionId = m.RegionId
[..]
where m.Day='12-5-2015'
and (c.CompanyId = @company OR @ByCompany = 0)
and (r.Region = @region OR @ByRegion = 0)
[..]
group by 
    Day, 
    CASE @ByCompany WHEN 1 THEN c.CompanyName ELSE 'ALL' END,
    CASE @ByRegion  WHEN 1 THEN r.RegionName  ELSE 'ALL' END,
    [..]
```

Doing it that way, we have simple and readable query, which will be maintable when we would like to add another columns for grouping, say subregion.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.Day AS Date,
CASE @QueryParameter
      WHEN EXISTS (C, CRP, CP, CR, CD) THEN (select c.CompanyName from Company where c.CompanyId= @company)
      ELSE 'ALL'
    END as 'CompanyName',

    CASE @QueryParameter
      WHEN exists (R, CR) THEN (select r.RegionName from Region r where r.RegionId=@region)
      ELSE 'ALL'
    END as 'RegionName',

    CASE @QueryParameter
      WHEN exists (P, CRP, CP) THEN (select p.ProductName from Product p where p.ProdId =@product)
      ELSE 'ALL'
    END as 'ProductName',
    CASE @QueryParameter
      WHEN exists (D, CD) THEN (select d.DivisionName from  Division where d.DivId = @division)
      ELSE 'ALL'
    END as 'DivisionName',
    SUM(Quantity), SUM(Sale)
    from ProductMetrics m
    where m.Day='12-5-2015'
```

Have removed the joins and added the sub query, Try this.